# Table making bug

Tags: feature-request, bug, markdown

Markdown than is on SE doesn't support table making.

Read the Markdown sytax specs page — section [Inline HTML](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html).

Example table in Markdown (and HTML) is on http://paste.ubuntu.com/1633733/. That works on some sites like [GitHub](https://github.com), but not on SE.

Why SE doesn't support this?

Comment: See MSO for this: [Is there any markdown to create tables?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/195914)

Comment: I saw it :). That tables are ok, but I wants full and true HTML table in MD. I can do that in GitHub, but don't here. Read post than i given (Inline HTML section).

Comment: Why do you want tables? This seems like a corner case rather than an actual need.

Comment: [Example](http://askubuntu.com/questions/253733/error-mysql-database-doesnt-support-transactions). I don't, but any1 want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are no mind-readers, so we can't tell you why there is no way to do it at this point.

But the reason for the "standard" markdown not working is this: [Table HTML is not permitted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites):

> We do not (and will not) allow `<table>` tags. Sorry. This is intentional and by design. If you need a quick and dirty "table", use `<pre>` and ASCII layout.

And, as [gertvdijk](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6051/table-making-bug#comment8951_6051) points out, this discussion has been had, and the answer is still the same:

**It isn't implemented. That's why it doesn't work.**

Except for yet again [asking for it to be implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138946/can-we-add-markdown-support-for-tables) and [using workarounds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/195914), there really is nothing else one can do about this.